# Set idle timer to dim but not lock

Tags: xcode, ios

Ok, I know its possible to keep the app alive by disabling the idle timer. I have an external scanner connected and every time the phone locks is somehow messes with the app and the scanner no longer works. I need to reset the app. If I keep the app alive with disabling the timer it all works fine. As I kind off want to preserve the battery I was wondering is there a way to allow the display to dim while not locking the iPhone so that when I pressed the home button the app would still be running with no need to unlock?

Comment: Is it necessary for the scanner to still works when the apps is not in focus? I would consider shutting down the scanner when the app isn't in focus

Comment: Well it need to work after a long period of time of inactivity but still save energy. making the scanner work all the time is a must for fast reuse.

Comment: So the scanner took a long time to initialize? This is for AIDC right? Perhaps you need to pick a faster scanner since it seems non-jailbroken iPhone can't keep your app running https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305314/keep-app-running-while-ios-device-locked

Jailbroken iPhone is ok though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779021/can-an-app-keep-running-while-the-screen-is-locked-on-a-jailbroken-iphone

That said, shouldn't there be another scanner with simpler interface? Say sending scanned data as keypress so it won't matter about your app state

Comment: Its a linea pro. The problem isn't that the scanner took a long time but needed restarting to be able to work again. Setting the idle timer to off solves the problem but then the problem of the battery arrives...

Comment: Restarting apps? That shouldn't be needed. Just dispose the scanner when the app is not in focus, and reinitialize it when the apps got focus